# Как решается проблема парсинга enum из параметра HTTP-запроса?

Tags: java, enum

В теле HTTP запроса приходят некоторые параметры, на основании значения которых нужно создать объект enum. Проблема в том, что параметры приходят в camel-case, например, `colName`, а enum перечислен в стиле констант: `COL_NAME`, то есть напрямую парсить не получится, так как java требует полного сочетания.

Какое решение в этом случае является оптимальным? Можно пренебречь конвенцией, и объявить enum в camel-case, можно написать костыльный преобразователь строк, а можно попытаться присылать уже подходящую под enum строку с фронта. В любом случае, ни одно решение не выглядит изящным, и, возможно, проблема в самой архитектуре?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```
    public class EnumExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Names colName = Names.findBy("colName");
            System.out.println(colName);
            Names.findBy("colNameTest");
        }
    }

    enum Names {
        COL_NAME("colname"), ROW_NAME("rowname");
        private String name;

        Names(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public static Names findBy(String name) {
            for (Names names : Names.values()) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(names.name)) {
                    return names;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Перечисление по имени '" + name + "' не найдено");
        }
    }
```